# How do I ensure correct data index when constructing a n-ary tree recursively

Tags: c, recursion, tree

Given that:
I have a consecutively stored data array with data for each node.
And the wanted tree construction is pictured below, where all numbers is node-id's.

How do I recursively construct the n-ary tree?

```
         0
    ------------
    1          2
  / | \      / | \
 3  4  5    6  7  8
/ \
9  10 ....... And so on
```

Heres the function implementation I tried to make:

```
void tree_constructor(nary_node* root, data *data)
{
  int i = 0;
  static int datacount = 1;

  if(root == NULL) return;

  if(root->data.children) {
    for(i=0; i<root->data.children; i++)
      append_child(root, data[datacount++]);

    for(i=0; i<root->data.children; i++)
      tree_constructor(root->child[i], data);
  }
}
```

I think it can be solved by implementing a queue where I store the function calls in some way and only do the other childrens recursive function calls after the first function is completed. Stil having trouble implementing just that though. And am still unsure if that is even the best solution.

Results from printing only my left subtree:
0 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 13 14 15 16 17 18

Expected:
0 1 3 4 5 6 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

The minimal example test: (ready to compile)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHILDREN 10
#define MAX_DATA 100

typedef struct data {
  int children;
  int id;
} data;

typedef struct nary_node {
  // Data element to hold data.
  data data;
  // Array of pointers to the children.
  struct nary_node* child[MAX_CHILDREN];
} nary_node;

void tree_constructor(nary_node* root, data *data);
nary_node *create_node(int children, data data);
void append_child(nary_node *root, data data);
void manual_print(nary_node *root);

int main() 
{
  int i;

  nary_node *root;

  data data[MAX_DATA];

  // The test-case data
  // Id's
  for(i=0; i<MAX_DATA; i++) data[i].id = i;

  // Children
  data[0].children = 2;
  data[1].children = 4;
  data[2].children = 4;
  for(i=3; i<=8; i++) data[i].children = 2;

  root = create_node(data[0].children, data[0]);

  tree_constructor(root, data);

  manual_print(root);

}

void tree_constructor(nary_node* root, data *data)
{
  int i = 0;
  static int datacount = 1;

  if(root == NULL) return;

  if(root->data.children) {
    for(i=0; i<root->data.children; i++)
      append_child(root, data[datacount++]);

    for(i=0; i<root->data.children; i++)
      tree_constructor(root->child[i], data);
  }
}

nary_node *create_node(int children, data data)
{
  int i = 0;

  //Memory for a new node is allocated.
  nary_node *node = (nary_node*)malloc(sizeof(nary_node));

  //All children is set to NULL.
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_CHILDREN; i++)
    node->child[i] = NULL;

  //The nodes data element is assigned to the input data element.
  node->data = data;

  //The n variable in data is assigned to the number of children.
  node->data.children = children;

  //The node is returned.
  return node;
}

void append_child(nary_node *root, data data)
{
  int i = 0;

  // A while loop to find the right index to append a child.
  while (root->child[i] != NULL) i++;

  // A new node is created at the last index.
  root->child[i] = create_node(data.children, data);
}

void manual_print(nary_node *root) 
{
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->data.id);
  printf("%d\n", root->child[1]->data.id);

  // Print left subtree for test
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[0]->data.id);
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[1]->data.id);
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[2]->data.id);
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[3]->data.id);

  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[0]->child[0]->data.id);
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[0]->child[1]->data.id);
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[1]->child[0]->data.id);
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[1]->child[1]->data.id);
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[2]->child[0]->data.id);
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[2]->child[1]->data.id);
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[3]->child[0]->data.id);
  printf("%d\n", root->child[0]->child[3]->child[1]->data.id);
}
```

Comment: How is the number of children determined at each level? The top node has 2 children. Then next level seems to have 3 children. Does this go on like this with each level having one more child per node?

Comment: Your question is confusing because you never mention the order of the data when it's in linear form.  Different thing: Why not just construct the tree with no numbers and then do a breadth first search to do the numbering?

Answer (score 1):

The queue idea is correct. Just do not recurse.

Create a queue of `nary_node *`. Kick start the process by creating a root, and pushing the pointer into the queue. Then repeatedly pull the pointer from the node, and create its children, pushing their pointers as well:

```
    while (!empty(queue)) {
        nary_node * node = pull_node(queue);
        for (i = 0; i < node->data.children; i++) {
            node->child[i] = create_node(data++);
            push_node(queue, node->child[i]);
        }
    }
```